# Open Sublime project and respect .sublime-project file from command line?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a project with a `myproject.sublime-project` file. If I open the project by opening this file in the Sublime Text UI, Sublime respects the exclusion rules in the file.

However, if I open the file in Sublime from the command line, it does not:

```
subl myproject.sublime-project
```

The excluded files and folders appear in the Sublime Text UI. The same is true if I do `subl .`.

Is there a way I can open this project from the command line, and have it respect the rules in `myproject.sublime-project`?

Here are the contents of the file, for reference:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "file_exclude_patterns": [
                "server/site/*.js"
            ],
            "folder_exclude_patterns": [
                ".sass-cache",
                "node_modules",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What build of Sublime are you running and on what platform? For me, `subl .` opens the folder and not the project (as I would expect), but `subl test.sublime-project` opens the project and the exclude patterns are applied. Maybe try `subl --project test.sublime-project`?

Comment: Sorry should have said, I'm using Sublime 3.2 build 3200 on OSX Mojave. Sadly `subl --project test.sublime-project` doesn't do the trick either.